# truffle unbox metacoin failed dowloading

Tags: npm, blockchain, truffle

Steps taken

`mkdir MetaCoin`

`cd MetaCoin`

`truffle unbox metaicon`

Stack trace

```
Starting unbox...
=================

✔ Preparing to download box
✖ Downloading
Unbox failed!
✖ Downloading
Unbox failed!
RequestError: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
    at new RequestError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/request-promise-native/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:1)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/request-promise-native/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:1)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/request-promise-native/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:1)
    at self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/request/request.js:185:1)
    at Request.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Request.onRequestError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/request/request.js:881:1)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Truffle v5.1.67 (core: 5.1.67)
Node v12.16.1
```

Comment: It was failing for me because of proxy. After removing that it worked..